# Unable to stop at a specified frame in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, macromedia

I have two pictures on two frames. There is a textbox in which there will be some value, based on which any of the frame will be played after click on button. But whatever the value is everytime frame 3 is played. I am unable to stop at frame 2.

```
on(release){
    myNum=parseInt(textbox1.text);
if (myNum == 2) {
   gotoAndPlay(2);
}
stop();
}
```

I should stop here as my condition that is in frame 2

[image]

But it comes here always that is in frame 3

[image]

Comment: Output **trace(textbox1); trace(textbox1.text); trace(parseInt);** before **myNum = parseInt(...)** I don't see problems with provide code, the problem is within data. Also, read up what debugging is.

Comment: Please just see my file. I have added my .FLA file link. This is a small project in my collage.[Flash file link download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00546445454832126661) @Organis

Comment: Sorry, I won't. You need to learn how to figure these kind of problems by yourself, that what **debugging** is. Basically, you put a lot of **trace(...)** to the problematic place to figure out which object/data is not what you expect it is.

Answer (score 2):

So, debugging. The point is to learn literally everything about data and objects you are dealing with. Somewhere along these traces you will see where it is not what you are expecting. The next step is to find out why.

A little research and you will know what makes your script to malfunction. Could possible be either of the following:

- **textbox1** is not a **TextField** instance name but a text variable name, there was such a weird thing in AS1
- the instance name is not **textbox1** but maybe **TextBox1** and you cannot access it as it is case-sensitive
- **textbox1.text** is not available because you accidentally have two copies of the same input field with the same instance name
- **parseInt** is not a function, I don't remember AS1/2 that good, who knows
- the result of **parseInt** is not what you expect

So:

```
on (release)
{
    // Check if button is working at all.
    trace("Release!");

    // Check if textbox1 is available.
    trace(textbox1);

    // Check text contents.
    trace("<" + textbox1.text + ">");

    // Check if parseInt is a valid function.
    trace(parseInt);

    myNum = parseInt(textbox1.text);

    // Check the result of parsing the text into integer.
    trace(myNum);

    // Check the condition.
    trace(myNum == 2);

    if (myNum == 2)
    {
        // Check if conditional clause works as expected.
        trace("Condition Worked!");

        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```